# svn - python 2.5 - ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, visualsvn-server, python-2.5

I have a python script for auto mailing when there is a commit in svn, but when i run the script it gives following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\AutoSms-Svn-Repo\test-repo-is\hooks\mailer.py", line 41, in <module>
    import svn.fs
    File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\svn\fs.py", line 19, in <module>
    from libsvn.fs import *
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\libsvn\fs.py", line 5, in <module>
    import _fs
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I even added required path variables for dependent dlls and python path
but still i get this message, even from command prompt

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem instaling subversion under `Windows 7` for `Python 2.7`.

The solution is simple  and has been tested. (but hard work to find and analize)

1. Download and install binaries from [Subversion](http://alagazam.net)
2. Make sure thet binaries folder (default: `c:\Program Files (x86)\subversion\bin`) is in your `PATH` system
3. Download `Python` files from site mentioned in point 1 ( [Subversion](http://alagazam.net) )
4. Extract `libsvn` and `svn` into `Python`'s `site-packages` folder
5. Open `cmd` (Window's command line console) and type: `python`. Then try to import `svn` module.

It should looks like (no error occured):

```
C:\>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from svn import core
>>>
```